# migrar datos de un array a otro php

Tags: php, array

tengo este array:

```
$geobd_urbanizaciones = array(
  "100100" => array("id_urbanizacion"=>"100100","id_distrito"=>"100","nombre"=>"Centro Histórico","id_departamento"=>"10"),
  "100101" => array("id_urbanizacion"=>"100101","id_distrito"=>"100","nombre"=>"San Andrés","id_departamento"=>"10"),
  "100102" => array("id_urbanizacion"=>"100102","id_distrito"=>"100","nombre"=>"La Merced","id_departamento"=>"10"),
  "100103" => array("id_urbanizacion"=>"100103","id_distrito"=>"100","nombre"=>"El Recreo","id_departamento"=>"10"),
  .....
```

lo que quisiera es un array de este tipo:

```
$nuevoarray["aca el id del departamento"] = array("aca el id de la urbanizacion,"aca el nombre de la urbanizacion");
```

Detalles:

1. Deseo generar este nuevo array para asi poder obtener todas las urbanizaciones de "id_departamento"
2. Intente con un `foreach` y `array_push` pero no me permite ingresar un "push" a un array con indice

Comment: utiliza $_SESSION, es comun en tus PHP

Answer (score 0):

si entendi bien, creo que este código te puede servir

```
$nuevoArray = array();

forEach( $geobd_urbanizaciones as $clave => $arreglo ) {
    if ( !isset($nuevoArray[ $arreglo["id_departamento"] ]) ) {
        $nuevoArray[ $arreglo["id_departamento"] ] = array();
    }

    $nuevoArray[ $arreglo["id_departamento"] ][] = array( $arreglo["id_urbanizacion"], $arreglo["nombre"] );
}
```

Comment: gracias amigo, lo probaré